# Generating Belender graphics in python

Tags: python

I have using GitHub codespace.

It has no graphical Linux terminal.

Is there possible to install Blender in linux codespace? (Which coding graphic for an web application)

Generating real time graphical animations with Blender in Flask framework in Python.

Assuming we has enough internet bandwidth and strong server.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Unfortunately I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, Happy new year. Please excuse me because my explanation lacking.
I want writing Blender codes in Python for an web application I'm going to write.
How can I coding Blender and my program execution playing defined graphic objects?

Comment: Is possible for me, preparing my GitHub codespace for `import` Blender libraries in my Python code? Installing what are prerequisites?

Comment: The Blender render engine is written in C++ not python, so if I understand what you're asking, it isn't going to be possible to use it in a web application.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please be so kind and rephrase your question. Maybe https://www.deepl.com/ will help you with a translation. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnEason, Is there an API for using Blender in Python? Which generating real time graphical animation in a web application wrote with Flask.

Comment: @quellenform, My language is Persian and deepl.com not support us.

Comment: The Blender API docs are  [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) but I'm not sure how useful they will be to you in your case.

Comment: You can build [Blender as a Python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) but it's not officially supported and you have to build it on your own.